# Conditional printed output

Tags: notebooks, printing

I would like to use a *Mathematica* notebook as a printable document with conditional output. If the condition is true, some parts of the notebook should be printed; otherwise they should not be printed. The condition that controls printing might be set in a cell at the start of the notebook, but this cell should not be visible in the printed document.

How could I do this? I have looked into cells, input and output in the Documentation Center, but could not find what I needed.

Comment: By parts you mean `Cells` or you want to split cells also? What version are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your answer!I am using version 9. I would like to be able to hide cells when the document is prepared for printing... Is that possible?

Comment: Closely related, possible duplicate: [(11898)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11898/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think you are right. Should I answer that question and delete or not this answer? I may also edit [tkott's](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/360/tkott) answer, it was before `Cells`, bacause it seems he is offline quite long.

Comment: @Kuba I think you should answer that question if you feel this is a duplicate.  You are not obligated to delete this one, but it would keep the site a little cleaner if you do.

Comment: Gabriel, I have closed this question as a duplicate, per the comments above.  (Your question will not be deleted but will remain visible to help others find the original.)  If you feel that this action is in error please reply in a comment starting with @Mr.Wizard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Too long for comment and there is not much information in the question but I would use `CellTags`. You can add tag by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> or via menu: Cell/CelTags/Add...

If you want to print only cells with particular tag you can create such document:

```
CreateDocument[
               NotebookRead /@ Cells[EvaluationNotebook[], 
                                     GeneratedCell -> False, CellTags -> "tag1"]
              ];
```

And you can print it then. And close without saving.

You only have to change `"tag1"` to change the content of new notebook.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, this was just what I was looking for!

Comment: @Gabriel I'm glad it helps :) If you restate your question to be more precise (*maybe a screenshot too?*) You may receive even better answers. Then, it is also good habit to hold on with accept (a day or two) to not discourage others :) Meanwhile, you can always upvote the answers you find useful.

Comment: @PinguinDirk Thanks :)

Comment: :) I like the answer, I once had to solve a similar problem. And as the Crtl drove me crazy and I might revisit that answer, I just had to